# How can I unzip the csv files downloaded from kaggle on google colab?

Tags: python, data-science, kaggle

I want to unzip csv files downloaded from kaggle on google colab by code below. But every time I run the command unzip, it says there is no such file or directory found, whereas colab says files have been downloaded succesfully !

```
!pip install kaggle
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import io, os
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3')
results = drive_service.files().list(
    q="name = 'kaggle.json'", fields="files(id)").execute()
kaggle_api_key = results.get('files', [])
# print(kaggle_api_key)
filename = "/content/.kaggle/kaggle.json"
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True)
request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=kaggle_api_key[0]['id'])
fh = io.FileIO(filename, 'wb')
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))
os.chmod(filename, 600)


!kaggle competitions download -c pubg-finish-placement-prediction
!chmod 600 /root/.kaggle/kaggle.json

!unzip train_V2.zip
```

Output : unzip:  cannot find or open train_V2.zip, train_V2.zip.zip or train_V2.zip.ZIP.

Even unzip train_V2.csv.zip doeesn't work !
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

In google colab **they might erase all your data if you are reconnecting or changing the Runtime type**. So be careful with your data.

Before you run the file you should check if the file exists. Try listing files using `ls` command. If the file does not exist try to place it again. If you are downloading it from the web you can use `wget` command.